# Resealing windows XP stops PXE working

Tags: windows-xp, deployment, pxe, wds

I'm trying to capture a drive image of a windows xp pro machine. I've gone through the steps and resealed the machine.

When i try and network boot the PXE instantly gives the message "PXE-MOF" and ends.

I have managed to get network boot to work on this machine whenever XP is not resealed.

I have tried Multiple times to get PXE to work after resealing windows, but with no luck. As soon as i unseal it, PXE works every time.

I know PXE is supposed to work independent of what's on the hard drive. Is there any way that resealing windows could cause PXE to stop working.

Comment: PXE should work even if you *unplug* the hard drive.  I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: I know that was what i thought too. I thought it might be a DHCP issue, PXE seems not to get that far

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "resealed"?

Comment: using windows sysprep
http://support.wavesco.com/kb/20090320/how-reseal-windows-xp-andor-vista

Comment: also what's the negative vote for, this is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 1):

this is very easy to trace with Wireshark
follow the DHCP transaction, you have to see the client gets an IP and 2 parameters:

1. TFTP server  IP
2. Name of the boot file (NBP).

sure it is a problem involving those DHCP parameters not provided correctly

Comment: The PXE doesn't seem to get as far as looking for a DHCP server, it exits before that.

Comment: the first thing a healthy PXE booting station does is performing a DHCP request...